# Prevent decimal rounding in Entity Framework database first

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to write/read latitude and longitude to a ms sql database using c#, entity framework - database first, and mvc.

The problem is that the lat/long are being shown with only 2 decimal places even though they are correct in the database.  The database has the fields as numeric(18,6).

I have modified the context file as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<STORE_LOCATION>().Property(location => location.LATITUDE).HasPrecision(18, 6);
        modelBuilder.Entity<STORE_LOCATION>().Property(location => location.LONGITUDE).HasPrecision(18, 6);
    }
```

2 Questions - Should I be modifying the OnModelCreating in the context file - even though it warns changes may be lost on regeneration and how do I keep the code from rounding the decimals?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I be modifying the OnModelCreating in the context file - even though it warns changes may be lost on regeneration and how do I keep the code from rounding the decimals?

No - implement a partial class of your context in another file and implement there OnModelCreating

As for the precision - have you checked the values in the objects in the debugger vs. displaying on a page?  The rounding may be occurring during rendering.

Try adding the `DisplayFormat` attribute to the property in the entity class:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.0#####}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Yes, the rounding is occurring in the rendering.  Any suggestions on how to prevent that?

Comment: are you assigning the value to a control that renders it?  you may need to specify formatting

Comment: Yes - using @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LATITUDE)

Comment: Thanks! - the DisplayFormat worked - kept me from having to write an extension

Comment: use `DataFormatString = "{0:0.000000}"` otherwise a latitude/longitude of 11.627440 gets displayed as 11.62744

Comment: [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.0000}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public decimal decimalNumber { get; set; }

---but when i enter value like 9.0098 it will change it to 9.0000 , here i need exact value only up to 4 after , so is it possible in decimal